# Alternative to sslSocketFactory in Java10

Tags: java, ssl, java-9, okhttp, java-10

I am using OkHttp and I need to ignore SSL errors for application debugging. This used to work in Java 8.

```
final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
            new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                }
            }
    };

    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    try {
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    } catch (Exception s) {
        s.printStackTrace();
    }
    final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

    //
    //.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory) throws error.
    client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory).build();
```

But in Java 9 and 10 I get this error.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: clientBuilder.sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory) not supported on JDK 9+
```

Is there another way to ignore OkHttp SSL errors in Java 9 and 10 without using sslSocketFactory?

Comment: SSL errors cannot be ignored. You need to *fix* the SSL errors, and you need to not disappear down rabbit holes like 'alternatives to `SSLSocketFactory`'.

Comment: @EJP Reread my question I need to ignore the errors so I can use a proxy server to make sure my requests are being sent to my site properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory, X509TrustManager trustManager)

In your code example you construct a X509TrustManager, just pass it in along with the socket factory.

Comment: Is there any other work around for this(Without changing code)? I,e,. passing some jvm options......  Saw here:  https://github.com/eleree/okhttp-gradle/blob/master/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/platform/Jdk9Platform.java    X509TrustManager -> Not supported due to access checks on JDK 9+.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that the single parameter version of sslSocketFactory() has been changed to throw the above error. You just need to refactor somethings and use the 2 parameter version of it, but you can still keep your anonymous class with the overridden methods.

Here is the above code refactored to work:

```
X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = new X509TrustManager() {
  @Override
  public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
      throws CertificateException {
  }

  @Override
  public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
      throws CertificateException {
  }

  @Override
  public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
  }
};
     
final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {x509TrustManager};

SSLContext sslContext = null;
try {
  sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
  sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
} catch (Exception s) {
  s.printStackTrace();
}
final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();


// Since sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory) throws an error 
//  use sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, x509TrustManager)
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, x509TrustManager).build();
```

Comment: The single parameter `socketFactory()` is not deprecated in Java 9, It is not even *part* of Java 9. It is part of OkHttpClient, where it has obviously been not merely deprecated but actively changed to throw this exception.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Thanks for the correction, updated.