# clientBuilder.sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory) not supported on JDK 9+

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I'm using jdk-1.8 and getting the following error on my tomcat server

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: clientBuilder.sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory) not supported on JDK 9+
```

It is working fine With same environment (jdk-8) locally but when a war is deployed to tomcat serer I get this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative to sslSocketFactory in Java10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594350/alternative-to-sslsocketfactory-in-java10)

Comment: Dis you solve your problem ? I have the same for a simple Main Class. Maybe a dependency we should downgrade (okhttp) ?

Comment: I have this error with OKHTTP lib. I'm using JDK 8 too.

Comment: yes @MychaL I was using Trust Manager for requesting server without ssl and it was not supported in JDK 8 update version I was using, I either had to degrade JDK 8 to lower update or remove the trust manager.

Comment: For my part, the problem exists with OpenJDK. But it is working with JDK Oracle...Seems the implementation is different with OpenJDK.