# Eclipse : clientBuilder.sslSocketFactory not supported on JDK 9+

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm getting this error on Eclipse oxygen 4.7.0, java 1.8

clientBuilder.sslSocketFactory not supported on JDK 9+

related to Eclipse, maven ..trying to update Maven : Alt+f5
the module okhttp3 trying to connect .. when resolving/processing pom

I dont have JDK9 at all.
Looked at all the other similar reports on stackoverflow, none is related.

Comment: get it resolved?

Comment: no .. installed new Eclipse version ;(

Comment: for me I downgraded from 1.8.0_251 to 1.8.0_241 and was able to work.

Comment: @Oxnard Hi, do you have jdk 9 installed on your system ?

Comment: @Oxnard With which java version do you want to run the eclipse with ?

Answer (score 6):

You can find a similar issue in [Eclipse bug 517113](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517113), with JDK8.

The error call stack indicates an external dependencies to a [library compiled with OpenJDK](https://github.com/takari/aether-connector-okhttp/pull/10)

[As seen here](https://github.com/takari/aether-connector-okhttp/pull/10), check also your JDK declaration in your Eclipse

> I changed code which was using JAVA_HOME as JRE coming with SonarScanner package.
> Once I changed it to default JAVA_HOME, it started working fine.

Other possible cause: wrong dependency, as show by [PR 3066](https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/3066/files) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50594350/6309).

Answer (score 6):

*I think you are running Eclipse Oxygen with JDK 9.*

If you don't want to, then I have a solution for that.

Update the **eclipse/eclipse.ini** by adding `-vm` parameter:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.700.v20180518-1200
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_251/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

This **.ini** file is from my latest eclipse. It may be different for other versions.

This will enforce eclipse to start with the JDK that you have added.

**Note:** `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8` will give you information upto which java version the eclipse can support.

Comment: For me, this error was appearing in pom.xml and it is resolved now by giving vm argument in eclipse.ini. Upvoted answer.

Comment: For me, this error was shown every time, when opening Eclipse and saving a file. Doing that trick, but on Linux, solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check your OkHttpClient.Builder(), change code from

```
sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory)
```

to

```
sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory, X509TrustManager trustManager)
```

For example:

```
// define sslContext ...

new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), new JEEX509TrustManager()).build();
```

And then everything will be ok.

Answer (score 2):

There are two versions of Java 8 as below:

1. Java SE 8 (8u211 and later)
2. Java SE 8 (8u202 and earlier)

So if you have installed "Java SE 8 (8u211 and later)" you will receive error: ***clientBuilder.sslSocketFactory not supported on JDK 9+*** in eclipse oxygen.
To avoid this error please install "Java SE 8 (8u202 and earlier)" from below link
*https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/archive/*

Comment: This worked for me, luckily I was able to find 8u202 and modified the eclipse.ini to use this version. I had previously had u212

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has come to face this issue when running Azul's zulu8 open jdk, try by taking zulu8 jdk of say 3-4 versions behind the latest. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I followed these steps to remove this error:
Earlier Code:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder(); 
 builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
```

New Code:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder(); 
 X509TrustManager trustManager = new X509DeployTrustManager();
 builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
```