# In eclipse 4.7, getting build error - clientbuilder.sslsocketfactory not supported on jdk 9+ in eclipse oxygen with jdk 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I am using eclipse oxygen(4.7) with jdk 1.8. I dont have java 9 on my machine. When i am trying to run my code , its always showing error occurred during build - clientbuilder.sslsocketfactory(sslsocketfactory) not supported on jdk 9+

Its also showing error mark on pom file but there is no error inside pom file. I am not understanding this bug.

I have tried few ways but none is working and i am not understanding why its giving this error when i am not using jdk 9 at all. Please let me know what can be done to resolve this issue which is not getting resolved since a week now.

I need admin access to change anything in .ini file which i don't have so can't do.
I am not able to do Maven update due to this error.
Project build also failing due to thid.

The error coming is - An internal error occurred during : "Updating maven project". clientbuilder.sslsocketfactory(sslsocketfactory) not supported on jdk 9+

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61899113/eclipse-clientbuilder-sslsocketfactory-not-supported-on-jdk-9

Comment: @suganthan none of the solutions on the link working for me

Comment: Are you referring to this [clientbuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html) class?

Comment: I would suggest to upgrade Eclipse cause Oxygen 4.7 is a bit old (28 June 2017 ) .. ?...

Comment: @Abra Eclipse Oxygen is 10 releases behind, so please upgrade. In this case it might caused by Java 8 that has not been updated for many years too (the error message points in this direction). Anyway, do not waste time by using outdated software.

Comment: ok , let me try upgrading eclipse, but my project is very heavy , setting up new workspace will take up a lot of my time , anyway seems like the only way out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this by installing eclipse version - **eclipse-jee-2020-09-R-win32-x86_64**
May be the issue lies with eclipse oxygen as pointed by others here. So migrated my workspace to new eclipse version and the issue is gone.